# NSUrlSession iso NSUrlConnection - uploading device token to a MySQL Database

Tags: nsurlsession

I'm trying to update my code from NSUrlConnection to NSUrlSession. The app is running fine, no errors, but the token is never uploaded to the MySQL database... I've really no idea? Should I implement delegates or am I doing something basic stuff very wrong here? :-)

```
NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];
//Information is only uploaded to SQLite database if 'deviceToken' is not null
if ([deviceToken length] > 0) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sampleUrl.com/do.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *varString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"deviceToken=%@", deviceToken];

    NSData *requestData = [varString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody: requestData];


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    /*NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:requestData completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
        //Handle
    }];*/

    //NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask2 = [session uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
        //Handle
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks and regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceToken"];

//Information is only uploaded to SQLite database if 'deviceToken' is not null
if ([deviceToken length] > 0) {
    // Create URL and URLRequest
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url.com/something.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Create the body
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *varString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"deviceToken=%@", deviceToken"]];

    // Create POST parameters and add it to HTTPBody
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [varString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Set up a simple and asynchronous NSURLSession to send data to the php
    // Set up the session configuration and header data
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    [config setRequestCachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy];
    [config setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{
                                       @"Accept" : @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",

                                       @"Content-Type" : @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",

                                       @"Content-Length" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[[varString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] length]]
                                       }];

    // Create the session and the task
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",
                  [error localizedDescription],
                  [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

        if (response)
        {
            NSLog(@"response description: %@", response.description);
            [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"tokenSent"];
        }

        if (data)
            NSLog(@"data description: %@", data.description);
    }];
    // Start the task
    [task resume];
}
```

Regards,
Tom